# Javascript array grouping and filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript array like the following

```
const array = [
"AB01-E-1000-0"
"AB01-E-1050-0"
"AB01-E-1100-0"
"AB01-T-1050-0"
"AB02-W-1000-0"
"AB02-W-1050-0"
"AB02-W-1100-0"
"AB02-W-1150-0"
...
]
```

Each string contain 2 parts - (e.g. the first section `AB01-E` and the second section `1000-0`). I would like to group the item by the first section (e.g. `AB01-E-1000-0`, `AB01-E-1050-0` and `AB01-E-1100-0` are considered as one group). And for each group, I would like to get the one with the smallest number in the second section (e.g. `AB01-E-1000-0`).

The processed array should look like this:

```
[
"AB01-E-1000-0"
"AB01-T-1050-0"
"AB02-W-1000-0"
...
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is an octet? what have you tried?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry I mean it should be split by 2nd  '-' and then group by the first section. Sorry to use the wrong networking terms to confuse everyone.

Comment: please add a complete result from the given data. is the data sorted at all or at least by the third (one based) section?

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated the questions and hope that it wouldn't confuse you. I want one item of each first section. If the first section has multiple items, then get the smallest second section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const array = [ "AB01-E-1000-0", "AB01-E-1050-0", "AB01-E-1100-0", "AB01-T-1050-0", "AB02-W-1000-0", "AB02-W-1050-0", "AB02-W-1100-0", "AB02-W-1150-0" ];

const getSectionNumericValue = (section='') => +section.replace('-', '');

const res = [...
  // get map of first two as key and second two as value
  array.reduce((sectionsMap, item) => {
    const firstSection = item.split('-', 2).join('-');
    const secondSection = item.split('-').slice(-2).join('-');
    const currentMin = sectionsMap.get(firstSection);
    if(!currentMin || 
    getSectionNumericValue(currentMin) > getSectionNumericValue(secondSection)) {
      sectionsMap.set(firstSection, secondSection);
    }
    return sectionsMap;
  }, new Map())
  // convert to array of pairs
  .entries()]
  // merge two parts for each record
  .map(pair => pair.join('-'));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

By having a sorted object by at least the third part,

```
AB01-E-1000-0
       ^^^^
```

you could group by the first two parts

```
AB01-E-1000-0
^^^^^^
```

and take a [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

```js
const 
    array = ["AB01-E-1000-0", "AB01-E-1050-0", "AB01-E-1100-0", "AB01-T-1050-0", "AB02-W-1000-0", "AB02-W-1050-0", "AB02-W-1100-0", "AB02-W-1150-0"],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = array
        .map((value, index) => {
            const key = value.split('-', 2).join('-');
            return { index, group: groups[key] = (groups[key] || 0) + 1 };
        })
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group || a.index - b.index)
        .map(({ index }) => array[index]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```